# OAuth2 flows - why doesn't twitter application require me to grant scope access?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

When I log in with twitter (for example) to some site, I am redirected to an authorization page that forces me to allow certain scope access to that site.

But when I log in to twitter itself (whether on the web or mobile apps) I don't get that same authorization page. Twitter web and mobile clients automatically get access to whatever they want about me.

Presumably twitter is using its own APIs with its web and mobile apps, so in terms of the OAuth2 flows, what is the distinction between the third parties using twitter API and twitter itself using its own API with its apps?